# Shiny: I am trying to plot a scatterplot in a shiny app but it only appears with one dot

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I have tried to plot the graph separately using ggplot (outside the shiny app) and it plots well so I know the problem is not with my ggplot code but with how the inputs in the shiny app are entered into the `renderplot({})` section. The inputs are the axes.

Code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)

data1 <- mtcars  

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(
        inputId = "xaxis", 
        label = "Choose a Variable for the X-axis of the First Graph", 
        choices = colnames(data1)
      ),
      selectInput(
        inputId = "yaxis", 
        label = "Choose a Variable for the Y-axis of the First Graph", 
        choices = colnames(data1)
      )
        ),
     mainPanel(
      plotOutput(outputId = "scatterplot"))
  )
) 

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$scatterplot <- renderPlot({
    req(input$xaxis)
    req(input$yaxis)
    ggplot(data1, aes(x = input$xaxis, y = input$yaxis))+geom_point()
  })} 


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution**

You are passing a string to your `aes`, which does not work. You should try

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$scatterplot <- renderPlot({
    req(input$xaxis)
    req(input$yaxis)
    gggplot(data1, aes_string(x = paste0("`", input$xaxis, "`"), 
                              y = paste0("`", input$yaxis, "`"))) + geom_point()
  })
}
```

**Explanation**

`aes` expects the bare column name  like in `ggplot(mtcars, aes(am, vs)) + geom_point()`. Note that we do not use quotatation marks `"` for *am* or *vs* (i.e. we are passing variable names and *not* strings). On the other hand `input$xaxis` returns a *string*. Thus, you have to use `aes_string` which is meant for working with strings rather than column names.

**Update**

Added backtricks to deal with non standard names.

Comment: I am aware of that. However, when I do aes_string, it brings:                 Error: <text>:1:6: unexpected symbol
1: Gini coefficient;        I believe this is because the names of the columns that need to pass have spaces in between them. That is how the data is. Do I now need to change all 30 columns  in the original dataset to include _ or  - in between them????

Comment: You should try to avoid non standard names. However, there is a work around - I updated my answer.

Comment: To change the names in your original data set you could do something like: `names(data1) <- gsub(" ", "_", names(data1))`

Comment: Yup, That worked (the update to the answer). Thanks :)